# Delete text to the left of a colon character

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to take the first column from my file (all rows except header) and delete text to the left of a colon character.

I get a 400 error.

As an example A2 (and subsequent cells in the A column) look like this:
[image]

```vb
Sub cleanLoginTime()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim tmp As String
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)  'this is your range of data
    For Each cell In MyRange.Cells
        tmp = cell.Value
        'output n - 1 characters from the right
        cell.Value = Right(tmp, Len(tmp) - 21)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Remove Left From Strings in Column

```vb
Sub CleanLoginTime()
    
    Const FindString As String = ":"
    
    Dim FindStringLength As Long: FindStringLength = Len(FindString)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FindStringPosition As Long
    Dim CellString As String
    
    For Each cell In rg.Cells
        CellString = CStr(cell.Value)
        FindStringPosition = InStr(CellString, FindString)
        If FindStringPosition > 0 Then ' string found
            cell.Value = Right(CellString, Len(CellString) _
                - FindStringPosition - FindStringLength + 1)
        'Else ' string not found; do nothing
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

- To make it more efficient (faster), you could introduce an array (`Data`), to access the worksheet minimally.

```vb
Sub CleanLoginTimeArray()
    
    Const FindString As String = ":"
    
    Dim FindStringLength As Long: FindStringLength = Len(FindString)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    
    Dim Data() As Variant: Data = rg.Value ' works only if more than one cell!
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim FindStringPosition As Long
    Dim CellString As String
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        CellString = CStr(Data(r, 1))
        FindStringPosition = InStr(CellString, FindString)
        If FindStringPosition > 0 Then ' string found
            Data(r, 1) = Right(CellString, Len(CellString) _
                - FindStringPosition - FindStringLength + 1)
        'Else ' string not found; do nothing
        End If
    Next r

    rg.Value = Data

End Sub
```

Comment: well it worked hence I marked this one as correct. Just for clarification. Did my code fail due to a lack of context in the cell count?

Comment: I don't know why it failed because I don't recognize this error (`400` looks like a `VBScript` error) and you haven't shared its description. It is best practice to use a worksheet variable so it is clear which worksheet the code will apply to. If any of the cells contain an error, an error will occur for sure. To avoid this, I'm using `CStr(cell.Value)`  i.e. you could use `tmp = CStr(cell.Value)`. Also, I don't know what will happen if `Len(tmp)<21`. Also, your code may behave differently when if it is located in a standard module or when it is located in a sheet module.

Answer (score 0):

I get a run-time error '13' because you need .row in

```
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
```

Do any of your cells have a length < 21?